# Best way to present pi rigorously without falling in circular logic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I think it is intuitive for everyone that the perimeter of a circumference is $k \cdot R$ for some $k \in \mathbb R$.

It should also be known that it is impossible to calculate $k$ without the notion of limit, simply because we didn't define the length of a curve on our distance axioms.

I want to find a way to explicit $\pi$ in the form of a series without using the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (x)}x = 1$ because this limit comes from the use of radians and I feel like it is circular to try to show that the circumferece/area of a circle is related to $\pi$ using angles in the form of radians.

One thing I did was to take a quarter of the unity circle. Divide one of its sides with $n+1$ points $X_i$ in $n$ segments $X_iX_{i+1}$ of length $\frac 1n$ each, let the perpendicular line to $X_i$ meet the circle on $Y_i$ and so the total length of the polygonal $Y_i$ would be:

$c_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac1{n^2} + (\sqrt{1-(1-\frac in)^2} - \sqrt{1-(1-\frac {i+1}n)^2})^2}$

If I could show this sequence to be increasing and bounded, then I would have a way to calculate $\pi$ and I could find a way to come to the more regular expressions for it later.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06752

Comment: It is "circular" in more ways than one! Ha!

Comment: @CameronBuie They say pi are squared but we know they're round.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed.  *Corn bread* and *brownies* are squared.

Comment: One method: You can define length of a curve by integration (or even more generally, by supremum of lengths of piecewise approximations), then show it is independent of parameterization, then use the parameterization $x \mapsto \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ for $x \in [0, 1]$ to compute $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as an integral, which can be expanded into a power series by using the power series.